# OOP and widgets

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to OOP an existing app.

I have a piece of data, "User Information", which is to be displayed in a text widget within a Labelframe widget which has an Entry widget as its labelwidget.

The "User Information" is, I presume, the data item to be OOPed and made into a class, so my question is: are the widgets included in the "User Information" class, or totally separate from the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general rule of thumb is to separate the data from its presentation, so keeping the user information in its own class is a good idea.

There are many advantages in doing this, primarily it allows the presentation to be easily changed without modifying the data. For example, if you later wanted to display the user information on a web page using HTML, you would write a HTML template that renders the user information, without modifying the class to remove/change the now irrelevant Tkinter presentation details.